# WebClient Giving 401 unauthorized error when credentials are passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, webclient

I am trying to access a webapi using `WebClient`.
When I set the the property `UseDefaultCredentials` to true, I am able to access the api. But the headers in the request will have the system login user details which I want to avoid. So I tried creating a network credential  and added the credential to the webclient.
Then the webclient always gives me 401 unauthorized error. It does not hit the Api. Below is my Code sample:

```
 var webClient = new WebClient()
                {
                    //UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")

                };
                var response = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://url/api/");
```

Comment: If an api responds that you are unauthorized, that is something to take up with the author of the API (or it is probably in their documentation). We on SO have absolutely no idea what this (unnamed) service does to validate its users.

Comment: when  UseDefaultCredentials   is set  true along with authorization credential it worked fine.

Comment: again, if you haven't contacted the people who host `http://url/api/`, why are you posting this here?

Comment: The service is written by me and there were no people to contact that is why i had to post here

Answer (score 1):

Try creating network credentials by passing only username and password.
In my case it worked.

```
Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"
```

Try accessing that API directly in the browser on the same machine.
One with domain, without domain.
You will see the difference.